# 'nslookup' is not working on multiple network interfaces cards in linux

Tags: linux, nslookup

I am having two NICs eth0 and eth1 for my Linux VM out of which one is in public and other in private network. When I am using nslookup for same by hostname its giving following error:

** server can't find "hostname": NXDOMAIN

I have checked all entries in /etc/hosts , /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 , /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 etc.
These all entries seems proper.

My /etc/resolve.conf is following:

```
domain in.rdlabs.hpecorp.net
search in.rdlabs.hpecorp.net 
nameserver 16.110.135.51
nameserver 16.110.135.52
nameserver 16.110.135.53
```

and netstat -r is :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
15.154.112.0    *               255.255.248.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
default         15.154.112.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: can you post your **/etc/resolv.conf** and the output of **netstat -r**

Comment: I have updated the question, pls check

Comment: it may be that the server 16.110.135.* can not resolve names for the network 15.*? try **nslookup  <hostname> 8.8.8.8** putting in place of <hostname> the host that you want to resolve

Comment: Non-authoritative answer:
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa    name = google-public-dns-a.google.com. -This is the output of "nslookup 8.8.8.8"

Comment: maybe I explained myself wrong. if you want to resolve the hostname **www.yahoo.com** you have to use **nslookup www.yahoo.com 8.8.8.8**. You should have an output like this:
Server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8 # 53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.yahoo.com canonical name = fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com.
Name: fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com
Address: 46.228.47.115
Name: fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com
Address: 46.228.47.114

Comment: LilloX, If I am doing "nslookup <hostname> 8.8.8.8" this is timed out , no servers could be reached

Comment: ok, I guess you could navigate and ping a server on the internet, right? Do you have a firewall? use a proxy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32302/discussion-between-linux-user-and-lillox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if your hostname is registered in DNS server you are using in /etc/resolve.conf. If not register it and check it should work.